# Run an application in background

Tags: linux, heroku, appharbor

As far as I know, it's impossible to run a custom application on Heroku and AppHarbor. I emailed them but there is no answer yet. What I want is run a Linux application (a web app also uses Linux) I made myself in background. Let's say it puts a text-copyright on every uploaded image.

Isn't it possible to run such an application? And if not, why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AppHarbor has [background workers](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/background-workers) and Heroku has [worker dynos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing).